# PostgreSQL query in grafana

Tags: sql, postgresql, grafana, postgresql-10

I am not able to see the output in grafana v 7.1.0 as per `group by coil_id`:

I use this query:

```
SELECT
  $__timeGroupAlias("time",$__interval),coil_id as coil,
  avg(drawing_force)*0.1 AS "force"
FROM drawing
WHERE
  $__timeFilter("time")
GROUP BY 1,2
ORDER BY 1,2
```

It shows result force on separate column and coil on different but need to see the result of force as per coil
[image]

But the same result is displayed in PostgreSQL 10. The query I used here is:

```
select avg(drawing_force)*0.1 from drawing group by coil_id order by coil_id
```

The result shows 7 coil with average force
[image]

Kindly suggest me to write PostgreSQL query in Grafana